# How to lock two coroutines but allow original coroutine to enter

Tags: kotlin, mutex

I launch a Coroutine to do some work. I need this to have a mutex. However, sometimes the `doWork` function calls `one()` again but a deadlock happens.

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
private val a = A()

fun start() {
    scope.launch {
        a.one()
    }
}
```

Then

```
class A {
   private val mutex = Mutex()

   suspend fun one() {
       mutex.withLock {
           doWork()
       }
   }
}
```

What I am doing causes a deadlock, because the `one()` is already locked. Ideally I would get something like `@Synchronized` in Java which lets the same thread come in, but I know Coroutines are not threads.

Is there anything I can use to solve this? I cannot change the problem too much because some of this code I cannot change myself.

Comment: What you're talking about is called a "reentrant lock", and is usually considered poor design. What you could do instead is pass to `doWork` a boolean parameter that tells it if it needs to acquire the lock or not.

Comment: see https://elizarov.medium.com/phantom-of-the-coroutine-afc63b03a131

Answer (score 1):

## Use communicating coroutines

You said you can't change some of the code, so this solution may not be an option for you. Locks aren't often a good fit with coroutines, though. A more idiomatic solution is to manage your shared resources by having different coroutines communicate with one another.

Instead of using a lock, you make it so that only one coroutine is ever allowed to access the shared resource. Other coroutines may send it work to do, but they may not access the shared resource directly. This guarantees that only one thing ever accesses the shared resource at any given time.

Say our shared resource is a function `doSomething()` that isn't thread-safe and should only be called by one thread at a time. We launch an [`actor`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/actor.html) coroutine that will receive requests. This coroutine is the 'owner' of the shared resource. Anything that wants to call `doSomething()` *must* do so by sending a request to this actor. Many things may send requests to the actor, but it will process the requests one at a time. Each time the actor receives a request, it simply calls the `doSomething()` function. Here I've used a `Request` class which can contain whatever parameters you need to pass to the shared function. It looks like this:

```kotlin
data class Request(...)

fun start() {
    val requests = scope.actor<Request> {
        consumeEach { request ->
            doSomething(request)
        }
    }
    scope.launch {
        requests.send(Request(...))
    }
}


suspend fun doSomething(request: Request) {
    // do some non-thread-safe work
}
```